# Kendo Grid Text Cut on Column Width

Tags: javascript, css, text, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid

http://dojo.telerik.com/IWuxI

In my example when the detail grid is expanded, I have a column with a lot of text -> the "Text" column.

The two other columns have a fixed with, so when resizing the window those stay the same, but the "Text" column expands.

Does anyone know if there is a way where I can always keep the Text column only show 1 line of text i.e. cut off the rest based on its witdh?!
Maybe through css?
Maybe there is an in-house function by Kendo but I have not found anything of the such.

Here is the Documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your dojo with what I think you want. 
[With style added for first line text only.](http://dojo.telerik.com/IWuxI/2)

all I have done is add the following attribute to the column:

```
{ style:"white-space:nowrap;" }
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Exactly what I was looking for